# My dog removed my yucca's bark, what to do

Tags: indoors

I bought a yucca palm yesterday, and when I woke up today I saw that my dog bit the plant's bark on one side. 
The yucca's trunk is about 80cm, the highest leafs are at about 180cm and the trunk has a circumference of about 32cm, of which the dog removed a piece of about 16cm x 20cm.

The yucca seams healthy apart from that... Will it make it? Is there anything I can do?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What was the environment when you first saw this plant?  Indoors, a greenhouse, out of doors in full sun?  Do you know when the last fertilizer was applied and what the formulation of that fertilizer was?  Talk to the people you purchased this from.  Get rid of the white rocks? You need a pot at least 1/2 the size larger, use only potting soil. If this plant was out of doors and now lives indoors you have a problem.  Rather your plant is going to have problems, sorry.  Watch out for other stuff your dog can get into for sure.  Perhaps a treadmill for your dog?

Comment: @stormy It was kept indoors, the last time fertilizer was applied is more than 3 months ago. I've since put a fixing gel on the spot where my dog removed the bark. The plant was purchased two days ago... It is now in a pot about 2 times larger than the one on the picture. The stones are on the plants to stop the dog from digging. She loves digging and I expected her to do this here too, not so much that she's going to eat the plant... :-) I've since chicken wired all the plants I purchased two days ago and started showing the dog alternatives to eating the plant, till now she respects that.. d

Comment: The best thing dogs love most is consistency.  Routine.  Learning the language of humans so that they are able to be part of your pack.  Get your approval.  They appreciate knowing the rules.  Clearly black and white, wrong or right.  They don't think the same way we humans do.  It is an honor to be a dog's human?  They need us to be the leader.  Consistent rules, simple words, a human always in control and always constant, consistent.  They soon teach you their language.  Such an honor.  She needs to know that digging in the pots is simply a NO no.  She wants to know her niche within her pack

Comment: @stormy True, though the dog's education is not a problem. I want to make it easier for her though and make it harder to fail, she's been adopted a few months ago and didn't see indoor plants before, she's been quite a problematic dog and has been abandoned 3 times before (she's two years old now) / spent most of her live in a shelter. I'm very consistent and she has strict rules here (which she follows), however, failure is always an option and I don't want my house full of soil if she fails.

Comment: @stormy apart from that, why did you recommend to remove the stones? Do you think that harms the plant/soil?

Comment: The room between the soil and the rim necessary to allow proper watering is already compromised.  There should be an inch between the rim and the surface of the soil.  Rocks also make great condos for insects.  Some dogs get great pleasure from digging and burying.  I am very humbled and grateful to people like you.  Thanks, Bambam

Comment: Thanks, I was afraid that the stones will make it more likely that the soil will get moldy. I didn't think about the insects yet, but see that that's a very good point. I'll remove them as soon as possible. @stormy

Comment: And the moldy soil is also a good point.  There is white stuff on the rim of your pot.  It could be accumulated salts or it could be coming from the rocks?  What is a fixing gel?  When bark is compromised we don't use anything on the wound any more.

Comment: The white stuff is from the rocks, I washed them before I put them on the plant, that’s just the water. I’ve since removed the rocks from the plant, the soil looks healthy. I’m not sure how to translate the word for the ‘fixing gel’ in English, the woman who sold the plant said it helps against fungal infections on the open spot. @stormy

Comment: And the moldy soil is also a good point.  There is white stuff on the rim of your pot.  It could be accumulated salts or it could be coming from the rocks?  What is a fixing gel?  When bark is compromised we don't use anything on the wound any more.  I really like how you said you were careful not to set her up for failure.  Perfect attitude.  I babysat a huge malamute for a year and one evening I caught him digging up a big pot of plants and soil.  He had buried his bone in it; I went to reach to pull it out, he moved so fast I didn't know I had a gaping 4" slash on top of my hand.  Big baby.

Comment: @stormy Ouch. Mine is a Argentinian mastiff, quite a huge baby too... She’s a good girl, she’s just been unlucky with her previous owners being unable to educate such a powerful dog properly; E.g. they couldn’t control her, but still left her without a leash, so she attacked a horse and was abandoned for it. We train a lot together, after we cleared who’s in the lead she’s learning amazingly fast how to behave.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83500/discussion-between-stormy-and-bambam).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the bark is only stripped from about half the circumference of the trunk, the tree should survive OK, though it may grow more slowly.

But if it is stripped all the way round, that is usually fatal, because the "veins" that carry the tree's sap from the roots to the leaves are close to the surface of the trunk.

You might consider putting a wire mesh or plastic guard around the trunk to stop your dog doing any more damage - i.e. a smaller version of the guards used to protect outdoor trees from animals stripping the bark.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've since been to the seller's shop and the told me the same, I've already protected it with a wire mesh... Ugly looking, but good for protecting the plants

Comment: The thing  about a tree surviving when the bark is half of the trunk is valid for dicot trees but Yucca is a monocot (which doesn't have real bark as a real tree, and different vascular structure).

Comment: With an active dog I would also do an inventory of all the plants within his reach.  Very many poisonous plants such as Lilies, lots of indoor plants are poisonous.  Dogs need a huge amount of exercise.  I've ordered harnesses and have a cart being made...custom made so my two guys can haul me around and work off their energy.  Exercise and chicken wire...

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do is to cut the plant off just above the damage, and let the top part of the plant root by putting it in soil (not to wet). Yuccas are easily propagated by cuttings.